# Configuring Unity Container in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, unity-container

I am trying to configure Unity with a Type that accepts as input a parameter of type Array:

```
      <type type="IPermissionCheckPlan" mapTo="CompositePlanTeamWorkroomMove" name="MovePlan">
        <constructor>
          <param name="checks" parameterType="IPermissionCheck" >
            <array>
              <dependency name="TWR_Move" />
              <dependency name="TWR_Copy" />
            </array>
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </type>
```

I am getting an exception when loading the container saying "Unrecognized element 'constructor'".

I am using Unity 2.0.

Regards

Comment: Are you sure are you using Unity 2.0? In 1.2 you would need to put constructor in <typeconfig> element.

Comment: I will double check on Unity and come back. Thanks

Comment: Hi Onof, I checked. Although I thought I was using 2.0, it wasn't. So I was using the configuration of 2.0 with DLL of 1.2. Now I moved to 2.0, but got something new:  "The injection configuration for parameter checks is specified through both attributes and child value elements."

Comment: Guess the entire structure has changed. There is no "<type>" element anymore, it got replaced by "<register>". I will change this later and run again.

Comment: Is it only with arrays, or all examples?  If you try a simple type, pass a string, does that work?  The class is called register, but <type> still works for me.

I'm using this:

    <type type="Project.ILog, Common" mapTo="Project.Log, Business">
         <constructor>
               <param name="includeLoggers" value="true" />
         </constructor>
    </type>

Comment: Type still works, it's an alias for register. I just thought "<register type=" reads better than "<type type="

Comment: I removed the "parameterType" and worked fine! 

<type type="IPermissionCheckPlan" mapTo="CompositePlanTeamWorkroomMove" name="MovePlan">
            <constructor>
              <param name="checks">
                <array>
                  <dependency name="TWR_Move" />
                  <dependency name="TWR_Copy" />
                </array>
              </param>
            </constructor>
          </type>