# The injection configuration for parameter <parameter> is specified through both attributes and child value elements

Tags: xml, configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm getting this error when trying to resolve a type:

```
public sealed class CustomApplicationUpdateProvider : ApplicationUpdateProvider
{
    IUpdateProviderController controller;

    public CustomApplicationUpdateProvider(IUpdateProviderController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    //more code here ....
}
```

using this configuration:

```
  <Unity>
    <typeAliases>
      <typeAlias alias="IUpdateProviderController" type="example.IUpdateProviderController, example" />
      <typeAlias alias="UpdateProviderController" type="example.UpdateProviderController, example" />
    </typeAliases>
    <container name="RealContext">
      <register type="IUpdateProviderController" mapTo="UpdateProviderController"/>
      <register type="CustomApplicationUpdateProvider">
        <constructor>
          <param name="controller" parameterType="IUpdateProviderController">
            <dependency/>
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </register >
    </container>
  </Unity>
```

I'm using Unity 2.0

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `parameterType="IUpdateProviderController"` attribute.

Related:
[Configuring Unity Container in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268815/configuring-unity-container-in-web-config)

Comment: Actually I did not even need to registrer the type CustomApplicationUpdateProvider. Unity is able to know you need to resolve IUpdateProviderController type to build CustomApplicationUpdateProvider. So the following configuration works for me: 
`code 
<Unity> 
<typeAliases> 
... same as before 
</typeAliases> 
<container name="RealContext"> 
<register type="IUpdateProviderController" mapTo="UpdateProviderController"/> 
</container> 
</Unity> 
`